# Enum.ToObject return default value when I tried to parse invalid value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse from value to enum by using Enum.ToObject method. However, when I used with invalid parameter, it seems always return default value such as 0.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldFail()
    {
        byte testValue = 68;
        TestEnum testEnumObject = (TestEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), testValue);

        //how testEnumObject is 68? dosent make sence.
        Assert.AreEqual(testEnumObject, TestEnum.A);
    }

    public enum TestEnum : byte
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 3
    }
```

How can I make function if the value can't be assigned with enum to throw excpetion?

Comment: `if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestEnum), testValue )) { throw new Exception()} `

Comment: Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Technically, TestEnum is just a byte. All values from 0 to 255 are "valid", just three of them happen to have names. That is a design decision one could have argued about, but that's the way it is.

Comment: That method is spec-ed to succeed if the value is outside of the range. From (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.toobject?view=netframework-4.7.2): _Note that the conversion succeeds even if value is outside the bounds of enumType members. To ensure that value is a valid underlying value of the enumType enumeration, pass it to the IsDefined method._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enum.ToObject Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.toobject?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts a specified integer value to an enumeration member.
>
> The `ToObject(Type, Int16)` method converts value to an enumeration
>   member whose underlying value is value. **Note that the conversion
>   succeeds even if value is outside the bounds of enumType members**. To
>   ensure that value is a valid underlying value of the enumType
>   enumeration, **pass it to the `IsDefined` method**

This says it all, so lets look at defined

[Enum.IsDefined(Type, Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a Boolean telling whether a given integral value, or its name
>   as a string, exists in a specified enumeration.

Sounds good so far!

**Usage**

```
if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YourLevelyEnum), 4)
{
    throw InvalidOperationException("OMG! Not.. even.. valid..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//using System;
//using System.Linq;
if (!Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum)).Cast<byte>().Contains(testValue))
{
    throw new InvalidCastException();
}
```